# Is it possible to simplify this code | Unity x Firebase

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

```
FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("/USERS/").Child(id).SetValueAsync(0);
FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("/USERS/" + id + "/").Child("A").SetValueAsync(0);
FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("/USERS/" + id + "/").Child("B").SetValueAsync(0);
```

This code requires many rows when creating a large number of new children at once.

This also seems to be wasting network communication.

Can you make this easier because `FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("/USERS/")` is the same?

Comment: It's only the same in the case of the last two, unless `GetReference("/USERS/" + id + "/")` and `GetReference("/USERS/").Child(id)` are equivalent.

Comment: You could generate a json including all the data and then use `SetRawJsonValueAsync` to write them all in one go ...

Answer (score 1):

From what I see your code will create this JSON structure

```
"UERS": {
  "$uid": {
    "A": 0,
    "B": 0,
  }
}
```

If so:

1. Your first call is not needed, as it is overwritten by the second call. Firebase automatically creates keys as you write values to them, and automatically removes keys that no longer have a value under them.
2. You can combine the two remaining calls by passing in a single dictionary:

```
    FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("/USERS/")
        .Child(id)
        .SetValueAsync(new Dictionary<string, int> {
            { "A", 0 },
            { "B", 0 }
        });
```